# The gentleman, a RxJs timer which wait for process to finish executed before next interval

Tags: rxjs

I want a timer/interval that run every `x` ms, and I will run some processes during the intervals.

What I need?
I want the timer to wait for my process to finished before triggering next interval, how?

*I am doing animation, so it is ok if some of the intervals are slightly longer. Just want to make sure all processes are finish executed.*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the delay to be at least `x`ms but always wait until the process completes:

```
const getProcess = () => {
  console.log('creating process...');
  return timer(500 + Math.random() * 1000); // mock process
};

const source = forkJoin(
  timer(1000),
  defer(() => getProcess())
).pipe(
  repeat(),
);

source.subscribe(() => console.log('sub'));
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jhvorc

`timer()` will emit just once and complete and `forkJoin()` will guarantee that both source Observables complete before it emits. Then `repeat()` will subscribe to its source again and repeat the whole process.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `forkJoin()` suggestion by @martin seems overly complicated. This is a simpler version, which does not trigger the same action immediately after it executed slowly:

```
const checkSessionTimer = defer(() => this.checkSession()).pipe(
  delay(3*1000),
  repeat()
);

checkSessionTimer.subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

For browser animations, running things every `x` ms is not encouraged anymore.

Instead you can now use [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) (ES6) and [animationFrameScheduler](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/animationFrameScheduler) from RxJS.